# How can i create duplicate records based the value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I have two tables in my database,  `Work_Order` table which is the source table where work order information's stored i also have `Work_Schedule` table which contains work schedules which tell peoples in the production floor what to build, when and how much to build.

> Work_Order Table looks like

```
Work order  ItemCode    Size          Qty    Qty_per_HR 
41051        600111    14L-16.1        55          10
```

I want duplicate the above work order line in work order table above based on the Qty per hour and automatically create a work scheduler as shown below.

where `TARGET  = Work_Order.Qty/Work_Order.Qty_per_HR`

> Work_Schedule Table

```
Id      Start Date/Time        End Date/Time       Work Order       Work Center     TARGET   ACTUAL
1001    2019-07-22 7:00AM      2019-07-22 8:00AM       41051             1         10       
1001    2019-07-22 8:00AM      2019-07-22 9:00AM       41051             1         10    
1001    2019-07-22 9:00AM      2019-07-22 10:00AM      41051             1         10    
1001    22019-07-22 10:15AM    2019-07-22 11:00AM      41051             1         10    
1001    22019-07-22 11:00AM    2019-07-22 12:00PM      41051             1         10  
1001    2019-07-22 1:30PM      2019-07-22 2:30PM       41051             1         5
```

My plan is to use `AfterInsert` trigger as soon as the user a work order create the duplicates.

> Schedule windows

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a natural for a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(datetime, '2019-07-22 7:00AM') as dt, workorder, 1 as workcenter, qtyperh as target,
             itemcode, size, (qty - qtyperh) as qty, qtyperh
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(hour, 1, dt), workorder, workcenter,
             (case when qty > qtyperh then qtyperh else qty end) as target,
             itemcode, size, (qty - qtyperh), qtyperh
      from cte
      where qty > 0
     )
select cte.*,
       dateadd(second, 60 * 60 * target / qtyperh, dt) as end_dt
from cte
order by workorder, dt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7392ed6e6edc22e3448880376862724a) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what are you after?

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  WorkOrder INT,
  ItemCode INT,
  Size VARCHAR(25),
  Qty INT,
  QtyPerH INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(41051,        600111,    '14L-16.1',        55,          10),
(41052,        600112,    '14L-16.2',        55,          5);

SELECT T.*
FROM T CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 1 N
  FROM master..spt_values
  WHERE [Type] = 'P'
        AND
        [Number] < (T.Qty / T.QtyPerH)
) TT;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+---------+
| WorkOrder | ItemCode |   Size   | Qty | QtyPerH |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+---------+
|     41051 |   600111 | 14L-16.1 |  55 |      10 |
|     41051 |   600111 | 14L-16.1 |  55 |      10 |
|     41051 |   600111 | 14L-16.1 |  55 |      10 |
|     41051 |   600111 | 14L-16.1 |  55 |      10 |
|     41051 |   600111 | 14L-16.1 |  55 |      10 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
|     41052 |   600112 | 14L-16.2 |  55 |       5 |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+---------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6df7a6b6096038d71c7566ab8ce0ec1c)**

Comment: Thank you Sami. yes but it has to be scheduled based hours like and the hours are `8-9`,`9-10`,`10:15-11`, `11-12`,`12:30-1:30`, `1:30-2:30PM`,`2:45-3:45` and `4:15-4:30` these are the hours of operation, can we add that as well? i have start Date/time and End Date/time

Comment: also can i use `AfterInsert` Trigger

Comment: What are you really want to do here? Are you looking to create a job? What does the trigger do?

Comment: Your solution is what I'm exactly looking for. here is what i would like to accomplish. On my scheduler app i have a drop down with a list of work orders coming from `WorkOrder` table when the planner select one  and Click OK, i want your solution above to trigger. I will add how my scheduler app window looks like in my question

Comment: i added a screenshot at the bottom where planners select workorders from `Work order` and create schedule, does that make sense @Sami ?

Comment: @Keven I'm so sorry, because I didn't understand what are you trying to or what your app will do, but it's for sure you're not looking for a trigger.

Comment: Thanks Sami, Ok forget about the app can we add the date and hour in your solution, based on 7-8, 8-9, 9-10, 10:15-11, 11-12, 12:30-1:30, 1:30-2:30PM,2:45-3:45 and 4:15-4:30 ? Ex: The first 10 build today's date 7-8AM then 8-9Am,....

Comment: You mean adding the `Start Date/Time` and `End Date/Time` columns to the resultset?

Comment: Yes, the hrs are the same for everyday these are hours of production