# Find the post link, related tags corresponding to each tag and answer at user level

Tags: sql, sql-server

In continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967044/retrieve-count-of-total-no-of-answers-corresponding-to-each-tag-at-user-level), I am trying to create a query that will:

**1. Find the count of total number of answers (that I have give in stackoverflow) corresponding to each tag and**

**2. Find the post link, related tags, title corresponding to the answer that I have given (at user level)**

I am able to get count of total number of answers using [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1217101/count-of-total-no-of-answers-corresponding-to-each-tag-at-user-level), through which I get

[image]

I get the post link and other related tags using [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1217054/1498221), through which I get

[image]

I joined both the above queries to get the desired result.

I ran the below query in the [data.StackExcange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) to get the desired result, but I did not succeed.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT T.TagName, COUNT(1) CntAcceptesAnswer
FROM Posts Q 
JOIN
  (
    SELECT Id, ParentId
    FROM Posts 
    WHERE OwnerUserId = 10348758 --Set your userid
          AND PostTypeId = 2
  ) A ON Q.Id = A.ParentId AND Q.AcceptedAnswerId = A.Id
JOIN Tags T ON Q.Tags LIKE CONCAT('%', T.TagName, '%')
GROUP BY T.TagName
)q1
--WHERE Q.Tags LIKE '%sql-server%' --Set the tag you want
INNER JOIN
(
select Title, Body, Tags, PostTypeId, ViewCount, CreationDate, Id as [Post Link]
from Posts 
where CreationDate >='2017-01-01'
    and PostTypeId=1
    and ViewCount>100000
    and (Body like '%deprecat%' or Body like '%Deprecat%' or Id in(
        select ParentId from Posts 
        where Body like '%deprecat%' or Body like '%Deprecat%'
    )
    )  
)q2
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. (Besides, I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: The OP is using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) @jarlh . We *all* have access to the data. The OP, however, would have been better off actually linking to their query on SEDE, rather than having us create another ourselves.

Comment: Great, but I'm a bit too lazy sometimes... [mcve] is what I want.

Comment: @jarlh , with respect, you really shouldn't expect the OP to replicate the data from Stack Overflow when you *already* have access to it. It's actually less effort to click the link and paste the OP's code (which generates an error) than it is to launch SSMS/ADS/your prefered IDE, open a connection to your sandbox instance, reformat their sample data into DDL and DML (as it's doubtful they'll supply DDL and DML) and then run the `CREATE` and `INSERT` scripts... open SEDE, Compose, run. Done... You *have* an MRE right in front of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are after:

```
DECLARE @UserID int = ##UserID:int##;

SELECT T.TagName,
       COUNT(A.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Id) AS AnswersInTag,
       Q.Title,
       CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',Q.ID,'/') AS URL
FROM dbo.Posts Q
     JOIN dbo.Posts A ON Q.Id = A.ParentID
     JOIN PostTags PT ON Q.Id = PT.PostId
     JOIN Tags T ON T.Id = PT.TagId
WHERE A.OwnerUserID = @UserID
ORDER BY AnswersInTag DESC;
```

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1217123?UserId=10348758)

Comment: Ah, how I miss that :/ 
Since the OP looking to his answers change it to `CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/qusetions/',A.ID,'/')`

Comment: If it's a direct link the the answer, it would be `CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/a/',A.ID,'/')` @Sami .

Comment: Maybe, but it works too, you can test it. eg: the link will be `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333762/how-can-i-create-duplicate-records-based-the-value-in-another-table/57333820#57333820` look at the `57333820#57333820` part. Anyway it's just in case

Answer (score 0):

Is that what 're you looking for?

```
SELECT CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',P.Id) PoostLink, 
       -- Other columns from P if needed such P.Title, P.CreationDate ...
       T.TagName, 
       T.Cnt
FROM Posts P
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT T.TagName, COUNT(A.Id) Cnt
  FROM Posts A 
  JOIN Posts Q ON Q.Id = A.ParentId
  JOIN PostTags PT ON Q.Id = PT.PostId
  JOIN Tags T ON T.Id = PT.TagId
  WHERE A.OwnerUserId = <YourUserId>
        AND A.Id = P.Id
  -- You can filter closed and deleted posts here as well if needed
  GROUP BY T.TagName
  ) T;
```

Comment: through your query I am able to get id, tag name and count of total number of answers corresponding to each tag

Comment: I also want to find post link, title, and other related tags corresponding to that answer

Comment: *"You can filter closed and deleted posts here as well if needed"* Note you'll need to use `PostsWithDeleted` if you *do* want to include deleted posts. `Posts` already has deleted posts filtered out, as they aren't in the table. (Learned that one recently the hard way, when doing a SEDE myself.)

Comment: That was from my prev A @Larnu I just C/P the comment with code :)

Comment: Couldn't you just replace `T.Id` with `T.*` or the specific columns you want to return @Bhavya?

Comment: @Sami replacing `T.Id` with `T.*` gives an error `Incorrect syntax near '*'.`

Comment: I *think* Sami meant replace `P.ID` with `P.*` in the top `SELECT`, @Bhavya .

Comment: The Title is (unsurprisingly) stored in the column called `Title`, @Bhavya ... You'll have to construct the URL yourself, using the columns. A Question's URL is in the format `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{Post ID}/`. For example, this question has an ID of `60970531` so it's URL is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970531/.

Comment: @Larnu even after replacing `P.ID` with `P.*` , I am not able to get the post link and title. See this https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1217115

Comment: Okay @Larnu, I will first try to construct the URL, using the columns and then get back to you. Thanks for your help :)